# Possible to delete a Column / Field from an already populated ADODB.Recordset?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

I would like to delete a Column / Field from an existing ADODB.Recordset object that is already populated with data.  A `Recordset.Fields.Delete` method does exist:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

...but if called on a populated Recordset one gets the error:  "operation is not allowed".

This is documented at the above link:

> Calling the Fields.Delete method on an open Recordset causes a
>   run-time error.

Doing a Recordset.Close clears the fields collection entirely, so that won't work - it almost seems like this method exists only for dealing with hand-rolled and manually populated recordsets rather than ones retrieved from databases?

Does anyone know of a way this is possible, even a fairly performant means of copying to a new recordset instance would be better than nothing.

**NOTE:**  Please resist the temptation to point out "you shouldn't be doing this, you should only retrieve the columns you actually want from the database!!!"  I am well aware of this.

**UPDATE**: As for the why:  I have these existing extremely complicated datasets to which I don't have access to the source code that physically creates them, and I simply want to drop some of the columns from them as they clutter up the UI where they are being viewed.  I explicitly care not at all about the .1 ms of time or .00000136 Mw of electricity wasted by bringing these unwanted columns back and then discarding them.

Comment: Is it okay to ask *why* you want to do this?

Comment: I could be wrong but you can only add or remove fields from a rs while it is closed. Alternative is what you have already mentioned. Instantiate a new recordset, append the desired fields, and then loop through the source recordset and copy over the values.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'm afraid you may be right but I'm hoping someone might have a better solution.  At the very least saving as xml then deleting within there and then loading back into a rs might be better as at least its using existing libraries & compiled code.

Comment: I think Siddharth may be right.  The only way I can see is creating and populating another recordset.  The code I found here would be easy to strip down (adding a filter on fld.name), <http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?374044-Creating-Disconnected-Recordset-Clones>